# Stream video and play in my mobile app using native script framewok including support of uploading video

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, nativescript

I am building app with nativescript hybrid framework, this application basically play and stream video over the wire, there are few thoughts coming in my mind

1. Use Youtube data API
2. Use platform native media player

i have few query over above option,

**Youtube :**

1. can i make it visible only through my app, it should not list on
   youtube,
2. if yes how can i use these api from Nativescript ??
3. can i use youtube share feature through my app??
4. is this a good idea to rely on youtube for this requirement or should i go      with my own implementation ??

**platform native media player**
as far as i know nativescript dosnt have inbuild media player, to use i have to call platform native player

1. is Nativescript right framework for this??
2. How can i steaming here??
   3: How to enable video sharing and all what youtube support (like, sharing , like disike etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relating to using YouTube in native apps. You need to use the YouTube sdk for that. I'm not sure if there's a plugin that's been made to simplify it (abstracted into a nice js API). I don't really follow all your points about it only being visible in your app. Perhaps you can expand on that.

Now the second mention of platform media player, I did some work on a video player module here: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer. So while NativeScript doesn't have video in its core, luckily the plugin (abstraction) has already been done. So you won't have to bother with the native parts of it unless you want to. To support the sharing and like/dislike you'd have to setup your own system for that. Unless you find a service for video that already includes options for that and you can use such services API. Going back to your first point, it depends on how much time/effort you want to put into the implementation if it's better to use YouTube or your own setup.